# Replace is only replacing the first instance of a RegEx Match in a line of my Python script

Tags: python, regex, replace

I'm trying my had at writing a BBS program and I want to be able to type in something like ^Qc6} and have it switch the text color. I have most of it figured out, by using a regex search and finding the text I want to match, as I read in the file line by line, it finds all the instances of what I want to match.

But when I use the .replace() method, only the first instance in the line I am processing is being replaced. Everything else is not until the next line. So I'm not sure how to correct this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import re

ansi_colors = {"c0" : "\033[0.30m" , "c1" : "\033[31m" , "c2" : "\033[0.32m" , "c3" : "\033[0.33m" , "c4" : "\033[0.34m" , "c5" : "\033[0.35m" , "c6" : "\033[0.36m" , "c7" : "\033[0.37m"}

display = open('sys.start','r')
for lines in display:
    match = re.search(r'(\^Q)(\w+)(\})' , lines)
    if match:
      lines = lines.replace(match.group() , ansi_colors[match.group(2)]).strip("\n")
      #print(match.group() + " should be " + ansi_colors[match.group(2)] + "this color.\033[0m")
      print(lines)
    else: print(lines).strip("\n")
```

Comment: It works fine for me with input data `^Qc6} ^Qc6} ^Qc6} `, i get `\x1b[0.36m \x1b[0.36m \x1b[0.36m`. Could you please explain your problem with sample data?

Comment: Yeah, the regex finds what it needs to find, but when replace goes through the file line by line, it seems to only replace the first instance of the ^Qc6} in a line. If you have multiple ^Qc6}'s or what ever code that would be used, it doesn't change the color for the second instance in the line.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using both *search* and *replace*? if the regular expression is not found - *replace* will return unchanged string.
As for your question - use *count* argument of the *replace* method [re API](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#module-contents).

(EDIT)
I have taken a closer look at your code - very inefficient use of re

```
re.sub(r'(\^Qc)(\d)(})', '\033[0.3\\2m', line)
```

does the trick - and you don't need dictionary, replace, etc

Comment: There is more than one code. While c6 means change text color to cyan, ^QH12} will mean print 12 backspace, or ^Q@file.txt} will mean display the file in the default directory named file.txt. It's an easier way for users and the sysop of the BBS to add colors, display files and anything else you need to do. So the regex is looking for the whole code, and the second search group is giving me the actual command code and arguments. Right now, I'm just focusing on colors and will deal with other functions as I add them in, one step at a time. :)

Comment: OK, that worked! Thanks! And it slimmed the code down. But I don't under stand what the '\\2m' does in the ANSI sequence '\033[0.3\\2m'.

Comment: OK, looks like this will only do the colors and not give me much in the way of allowing other codes later on. And since .sub doesn't seem to support match groups like I was using in the above code, I'm limiting myself later on down the line unless there is another solution. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: \\2 means - replace with second matched group. RTM 
http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html. Obviously, I could not suggest what else you could do - since you did not ask it in the first place. If you replace (\d) with ([^}+) - it will solve you the 3rd case - although you may need to change the replacement string.